# AWS Gateway API, setup a lambda as a proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, aws-api-gateway

In AWS, I have an EC2 with a private IP in a VPC with no online access.
I sat up a private VPC endpoint to a Gateway API following the instructions here: [How to create a VPC endpoint for API Gateway](https://dulajra.medium.com/how-to-create-a-vpc-endpoint-for-api-gateway-a84bc7eeba28)

So now, I can send requests to a Lambda:
`curl -i "https://xxxxx-vpce-xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test/"`

For now, my lambda just returns a message, no matter the request:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event, context)
 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I would like to have the lambda act as an outbound proxy so that when I run:
 `curl -i --proxy "https://xxxxx-vpce-xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test/" https://google.com`
I get the content of `https://google.com`

My plan was to run that last curl command, print the event/content and figure out what could be done.
But when I run it, I get a 403 Forbidden error, with no entries in the Gateway API logs.

I am not sure what I am trying to do is even possible. But that's what I am trying to determine. How can I do it if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use API Gateway as a HTTP Proxy which is the reason why you are getting "403 Forbidden error".

You can look into what is happening by using --trace-ascii option in curl.

Use this command :

```
curl -i --trace-ascii - --proxy "https://xxxxx-vpce-xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test/" https://google.com
```

What you will see will be something like this in log :

```
=> Send header, 112 bytes (0x70)
0000: CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
0021: Host: xxxxx-vpce-xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
00XX: User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
00XX: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Basically, curl is issuing a HTTP CONNECT verb to api-gateway instead of a POST or GET or PUT or DELETE and API-Gateway is blocking CONNECT verb hence 403 error.

What you are trying to do is to use API-Gateway as a HTTPS proxy, which is by design blocked. The call will not even reach your lambda, it will be rejected at API-Gateway.

You MAY design a "high-level" proxy out of your lambda + API-Gateway combination BUT I highly doubt you will be able to make a HTTPS proxy out of API-Gateway like you are trying.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.